# Convert .mat files to .txt files

Tags: matlab

Wha am I doing wrong?I need to convert .mat file (MATLAB binary format) to a .txt file so as to read it in C++ later on. I tried follwing in MATLAB:

```
>>load('file.mat')
>>Conten = who;
>>save('file.txt', Conten{:}, '-ascii')
```

But, it gives warning: Attempt to write unsupported data type to an ASCII file.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance...

Comment: From the docs for the ascii format: `Each variable must be a two-dimensional double or character array.`. That's obviously not the case...

Comment: @Blacktempel this is in MATLAB

Comment: @Blacktempel it is not supposed to be C++, `file.txt` is supposed to be read in C++ later on.

Comment: how to convert .mat to .txt then??

Comment: it depends on the content of the mat-file. It could be everything. Post some code together with examplary content.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is `who`, e.g. what type of data and why do you want to read it from C++?

Comment: Well you'll have to check what's inside the mat-file and save things in an appropriate way. If you want a generic solution, read the mat-file from C++ directly, using e.g. the `matio` library.

Comment: @learner: only way I see is to convert everything that is *not* a 2D `double` or `char`, to a 2D `double` or `char`. Or implement your own text writing utility that loops through the contents of `whos`.

Comment: By the way: Using `who` you're of course also picking up all other stuff that's in your workspace, not only what was loaded from the mat-file. You should rather use `whos('-file', 'file.mat')'.

Comment: @sebastian i will try it out..and also the matio library....thanks!
THANKS ALL...